# How Safe is this 5-way ceiling lighting DIY install

Tags: electrical, ceiling, light-fixture

I've installed a 5-way ceiling light in a relatives house yesterday and whilst I've been more than careful in all it's prepartion and install, and being over caustious (without big paranoid!) I'm a little concerned and would like some feedback on the job in question.

My primary concern here regarding safety is:

Is the 10amp chocbloc sufficient for the load of 5* 42w halogen lights?

Is the 'manual' twist of 5*neutral 'blue' cabling from each arm safe twisted into a single 10amp chocblok connector?

Can I decrease the risk by double insulating say the single Brown arm    combine to live supply?

Here is what I did. The light in question is very similar in model ([Wilko 5 Arm Chandelier Metal Ceiling Light Fitting Cream](http://www.wilko.com/ceiling-lighting/wilko-5-arm-chandelier-metal-ceiling-light-fitting-cream/invt/0326168)) to this UK light.

After reading the instructions thoroughly, prep the lighting unit, turning off power, I removed the previous rose etc and prepared the cable wires. All ok.

The lighting unit instructions stated that the neutral (black) 'blue' needed to be twisted together which I did and I cut a chocbloc down to joined 4-units (chocbloc rated at 10amps), and carefully binded/twisted them in, tightened them in with the said screws. I decided to sequence the cables as follows: looking right to left: bloc #1 G/Y earth, #2 Black (marked Red) live switch, #3 left empty, #4 live loop. I purposely kept the live supply to twisted Brown arm cables separate and to the left of the chocbloc (it is insulated with black tape). At this moment in time, I'm remember ting this from memory, I'm to double check this later today and will emend the text here.

My concern is the (if any) risk overtime to fire etc (not that it's left on for hours, it's a landing light. I think I've been over cautious, but would like an opinion.

edit: increase to decrease, typo on my part (-:

Comment: A photo would help.

Comment: Haven't got one to hand at mo, but will have later today (15.45 GMT) so will post. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the 10amp chocbloc sufficient for the load of 5* 42w halogen lights?

Yes, 5 x 42 W = 210 W, 210 W / 240 V = 0.875 A

> Is the 'manual' twist of 5*neutral 'blue' cabling from each arm safe twisted into a single 10amp chocblok connector?

Five is a lot. I'm surprised the fitting didn't provide a better way to unite them. The main issue is ensuring that the connection is tight and that enough of all wires are clamped under the screw. If in doubt you can use multi-way connectors such as Wago push-fit or lever-clamp connectors which have a separate position for each wire.

[image]

> Can I increase the risk by double insulating say the single Brown arm combine to live supply?

I'm sure you mean *decrease* the risk but I don't understand what you mean by double insulating.

For general lighting applications there isn't any need to apply insulating tape so long as everything is done correctly.

The live and neutral wires are adequately insulated and you shouldn't trim more than the minimum insulation needed to fully insert the wires into the connector. After doing so, there should be no exposed copper, the screw heads in the connector are protected by the plastic within which they are recessed, there should be no danger of metal to metal contact.

Any metalwork in the light fitting that can conceivably come into contact with people should be connected to protective earth.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. yes, I meant 'decrease' (-: Today, I went back to the job, doubled checked the fitting, but all my previous efforts appeared good. I checked all connectors, all were fine inc earth. I ensured that the 4-way chocblok (Black neutral, earth connections) was layed eitherside opposite the single UK 'Brown' (red) live the connector; I wrapped a layer of black tape around it (what I meant by 'double insulation in my OP) for extra peace of mind. All the cabling was layed carefully in the light-fitting head and screwed tight before putting power back on. It appears aok.

Comment: Those Wago look really good, I'll check them out in the UK on Screwfix. BTW, I'm in IT and build my own computers, but the above DIY had me worried. Thanks to this Stackexchange, I can call on future issues now. Thanks again. (-: